# Which followers are a different level than the Dragonborn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing through Skyrim again, and when choosing what follower to use at my level, I noticed that the Elder Scrolls Wiki lists [Mjoll the Lioness](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Mjoll_the_Lioness)'s level as

> PC×1.25 (10-40)

[UESP says this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mjoll_the_Lioness) as well.

So, if I'm level 28, Mjoll should be level 35.

Are there any other permanent followers with a level that's different than the Dragonborn's? This is assuming that the Dragonborn's level is currently within the follower's range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I checked, the Elder Scrolls Wiki did not list a multiplier for every follower, but UESP did.

There are three followers with multipliers less than 1, and two with multipliers over 1:

[Roggi Knot-Beard](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Roggi_Knot-Beard): PC×0.75 (range=6-20)
[Sven](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sven): PC×0.75 (range=6-20)
[Adelaisa Vendicci](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Adelaisa_Vendicci): PC×0.9 (range=6-25)

[Mjoll the Lioness](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mjoll_the_Lioness): PC×1.25 (range=10-40)
[Erandur](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Erandur): PC×1.5 (range=6-50)

This explains why Erandur is so awesome, as anyone who has used him has probably noticed.

Most animal followers and a few people have set levels that do not change. [Talvas Fathryon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Talvas_Fathryon), for instance, is always level 25.

Comment: Looks like you skipped quest followers.

Comment: @amaranth Yeah, I'm not counting those, since I can't choose them as followers outside the quest. Also, that section is noted as being incomplete on UESP.

Comment: @amaranth Added the word "permanent" to the question, to clarify.